# Can two panels share a uicontrol in a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, panel, matlab-guide, uicontrol

I've got a MATLAB GUI that has different aspects of functionality, each with their own panel of uicontrols. When one panel is selected, the other one is set to invisible, and vice-versa. However, they share some of the same inputs in the form of a popup menu. Can I include a 'clone' instance of the menu on the second panel somehow? I'd like to avoid as many redundant callbacks and uicontrols as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if the uicontrol was a direct child of the figure, you may be able to put it in front of everything.

A much simpler solution is to use the same callback for multiple uicontrols. In the property editor, you can modify the callback name and set it to a common callback function. Additionally, you can create a field (e.g. `myPopupH`) in the `OpeningFcn` of the GUI, in which you store the handles of the popups that should behave the same way. Then, in the callback, you'd use `hObject`, i.e. the first input argument, for all the `get` calls (to access the modified state of the popup-menu), but you'd use `handles.myPopupH` in all the `set` calls, so that you can ensure that both popups always have the same state. Thus, the ui-object may be redundant, but all the code (which is much more critical) only exists in a single copy.

One place where I routinely use a single callback for multiple ui elements is the close request function which is accessed from the "Cancel"-button as well as from the "X" that closes the figure, and possibly from one of the "File"-menu items.